# At Val d'amour they play a part - what does "play a part" mean?

Tags: idioms, poetry

A passage from a song called At Val d'Amour from musical "Notre-Dame de Paris":

> Ladies of love my heart is sore, I am Gringoire the troubadour.
>   I'm sick with love you have the cure behind the doors at Val d'amour.
>   Guitars implore come one come all, come take your tour of Val d'amour.
>   At Val d'amour they **play a part**, give them your money not your heart.
>   Beneath the sheets your love will flower, it'll last the night or last an hour.

I don't understand what they mean by **play a part**.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*Play* here has the theatrical meaning: just as a *play*, noun, is the script for a theatrical performance, to *play*, verb, is to act—in fact, at one time actors were usually called 'players'.

And a *part* is what an actor plays--the character he represents in the play.

Thus to *play a part* is to *perform a role*. Perhaps the most famous use of the phrase is in Shakespeare's  *As You Like It*:

> All the world’s a stage,
>   And all the men and women merely players.
>   They have their exits and their entrances,
>   And one man in his time plays many parts

So Gringoire is reminding the patrons of the whorehouse that the ladies there merely pretend the passion they exhibit.